# PERFORMANCE - Filter by a specific query block in a SELECT UNION

Tags: sql-server

I use to work with views that contain UNION statements collecting data from several sources similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM SourceTable1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM SourceTable2
UNION
...
SELECT * FROM SourceTableN
```

Usually, I only need data from one of the sources, the views contain the name of the source so I can filter by that but when the tables are big the performance decreases because the search must be done at each table.

Is there any way to tell the query planner the subquery in which the desired data is?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, next simple approach may help to apply a filter, based on source name:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       *,
       'SourceTable1' AS [SourceName]
       FROM SourceTable1
    UNION 
    SELECT 
       *,
       'SourceTable2' AS [SourceName]
       FROM SourceTable2
    UNION 
    SELECT 
       *,
       'SourceTableN' AS [SourceName]
       FROM SourceTableN
) t
WHERE t.SourceName = 'SourceName1'
```

Comment: I am concerned about the performance, would this avoid the query planner to look inside each SourceTable?